# IP telnet not Happening

Tags: telnet, connection

i've servers as A,B and C.A is windows machine and B & C are Linux.i'm able to ping both B and C from A.
A is able to telnet B on port 1521 but Telnet is not happening from A to C on the same port.
Can anyone gives me an idea about this issue? How we can Resolve? Does i've to add the routes on C seems like have to make some channges in C.C is able to accept connections from other clients.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping C from A, then your routes are correct. If you can telnet C from B, then your telnet on C also listens correctly (you can verify with `netstat -tan`, by the way). If C accepts telnet sessions from B but not from A, then you may have the situation that:

- C filters or drops packets from A (check your firewall, iptables etc.)
- or A supresses outgoing connections to C on your telnet port (firewall)